# how to set row number with in sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

want to return row with a row number, not IDX.

with in
python 3.6.5
SQLAlchemy==1.2.15
aws rds

```py
query = session.query(product)
row_number_column = func.row_number().over(order_by='IDX').label('row_num')
query = query.add_column(row_number_column)
```

when run query.all() return syntax err.

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064,
>   "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(ORDER BY product.`IDX`) AS `ROW_NUM` \nFROM product' at line
>   1") [SQL: 'SELECT product.`IDX` AS `product_IDX`, product.`PD_SERIAL`
>   AS `product_PD_SERIAL`, product.`PD_COUNT` AS `product_PD_COUNT`,
>   /.../ product.`UPDATE_TIME` AS `product_UPDATE_TIME`, row_number()
>   OVER (ORDER BY product.`IDX`) AS `ROW_NUM` \nFROM product']
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacky way of doing it without the `ROW_NUMBER` function (not present in MySQL server < 8.0):

```
session.execute('SET @row_number = 0')
query = session.query(product).order_by('IDX')
row_number_column = "(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS row_num"
query = query.add_column(row_number_column)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will run tomorrow morning!

Comment: After a few days of searching, I'm having a hard time interpreting the following phenomena:

before add_column

query.first() -> <model.pad.Product object at 0x0000017F78B5D358>

after add_column

query.first() = (<model.pad.Product object at 0x0000017F78B5D358>, 1)

I think that value of 1 should go inside the object, but it sticks outside.

Comment: @ParkDyel is that a requirement for you? I think it might be hard to do. I would normally just loop over the results for example `for product, row_num in result: ...` and then you have the Product and the related row number as variables inside the result set loop.

Comment: As you said, I assigned a value directly in the for statement. I tried to manipulate it inside a sql statement but it wasn't an easy approach.

Really, Thanks!! 
Here is Thanksgiving. I wish you plenty of abundance.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a database feature not present in your MySQL version.

The "invalid" SQL part is:

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY product.IDX) AS ROW_NUM
```

This is actually correct SQL code that uses so-called "window functions", of which `row_number()` is a very simple one. Those are well-known in PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle and almost every other database. MySQL joined the party lately with MySQL 8.0 (resp. MariaDB 10.2):

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

There are some workarounds, but those are ugly and not generated automatically by SQL Alchemy.

I propose to either upgrade your MySQL or MariaDB server, or to instead count up the row number on Python side while iterating over the result.

Comment: Isn't this answer only correct for MySQL server versions < 8.0?

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand Thanks for the hint. I adjusted my answer accordingly.